# Meta-analysis of public 16S data

Tags: metadata, bioinformatics

I am trying to start a meta-analysis for which I want to extract some 16S-based information from public databases. Moreover, I want to relate this information with any metadata found in the associated studies (everything from environmental variables to sequencing details).

For this, I realized some databases are available, like NCBI-Nucletotide, NCBI-SRA and EMBL-EBI-ENA, but I am not sure about which one to use or whether I can use them all.

How can I filter only whole 16S sequences? Or even the most used 16S region?

One more thing would be how can I extract all the corresponding metadata?

Has anyone here tried this or anything similar before?

Comment: Probably you'll get an answer if you post in bioinformatics.stackexchange.com instead of here. There are some users familiar with those databases and the type of data you are using... (or you could post an answer if you got something after 4 years :)